# Command to open 68 MB pdf file uses all system resources and fails, but it works on other files

Tags: launcher, libreoffice, ubuntu-mate

When I double click this pdf with Thunar, it opens quickly.

But when I use this command in a launcher, it uses 100% of CPU and half of RAM, yet it never opens the 68 MB pdf file?

```
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/swriter --nologo /SDB1_Mountpoint/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04/MazdaCX7CX-7ServiceRepairWorkshopManual2007-2012.pdf
```

I use this command for other smaller files with no problemos.

I even tried moving the file to my local hard drive which is a faster drive.

What is the reason and can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you using LibreOffice to open a .pdf file? What happens if you just double-click on the .pdf? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibreOffice Writer (or really Draw in this case) is not a PDF viewer. But it can edit PDFs. So it may be absolutely expected that it requires many resources to render/convert PDF with many schemes and graphics.

Use PDF viewer instead:

- Atril (default in MATE);
- Evince (default in GNOME);
- Okular (default in KDE);
- etc.